# What constitutes "Magical Healing"?

Tags: dnd-5e, healing, injury

DMG 272 says that "magical healing" can remove a limp, heal an internal injury, or mend a broken rib. Since these are considered to be "Lingering Injuries" it seems crazy that a simple "Cure Wounds" would end the condition. (Of course, I could be wrong).

So what does the term "Magical Healing" mean? Is it any magical effect that restores Hit Points? Do magical potions count?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Healing is constantly referred to in the rules as regaining hit points. The *Lingering Injuries* table says magical healing so that's exactly what it means; hit points regained through magical means.

The PHB says:

> magical methods such as a *cure wounds* spell or a ***potion of healing*** can remove damage in an instant.

So yes, potions count.

In the case of a severed appendage then you have to use a spell that specifically says it restores such things (like *Regenerate*).